# Graded Betti Numbers of a Graded Ideal with Linear Quotients

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals, betti-numbers

**Exercise 8.8(a) in *Monomial Ideals* by Herzog and Hibi:**

> Let $I\subset S=K[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ be a graded ideal which has linear quotients with respect to a homogeneous system of generators $f_{1},...,f_{m}$ with $\deg f_{1}\leq\cdots\leq\deg f_{m}$. Prove that 
>   $\beta_{i,i+j}(I)=\sum\limits_{k=1,\ \deg f_{k}=j}^{m}$
>   $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
> r_{k}\\
> i
> \end{array}
> \right),$
>   where $r_{k}$ is the cardinality of the minimal system of linear forms which generate $(f_{1},...,f_{k-1}):f_{k}$.

The case when $\deg f_{1}=\deg f_{2}=\cdots=\deg f_{m}$ may be proved easily because in this case $I$ has linear resolution.

When degrees are not equal, how to prove? We know from Theorem 8.2.15 in this book that $I$ is componentwise linear.